# Binding to a custom XAML control property won't work

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to create a Windows 10 UWP application with C# and XAML.
At this point I'm quite stuck with data binding in item templates.

So basically, I have a ViewModel, that is bound to the XAML controls.

I want to bind the data model to a property of a custom control. The thing is that some things work, some don't and I can't really understand why.

So this binding **works:**

```xml
  <GridView   ItemsSource="{Binding MediaElementId}" >
       <GridView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
           </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
   </GridView>
```

But when i put other things insted of the TextBlock, it won't work.

For example these bindings **won't work**:

```xml
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding  Path=.}"/>
```

```xml
 <controls:CustomControl Test="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

```xml
 <controls:CustomControl Test="{Binding Path=., RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

```xml
 <controls:CustomControl Test="{Binding}"/>
```

So, I basically found documentation, that {Binding} is equivalent with {Binding Path=.}, but in this example it doesn't really seem that way.

You can try it yourself in a project, where I isolated the issue:
https://bitbucket.org/MrGreeny/pivottestapp/src/4edee74acfac6dbb4f9f042acaf389cc6fd90a31?at=master

**Edit:**
The property is a pretty simple one:

```cs
    private string test;

    public string Test
    {
        get { return null; }
        set
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(value);
           //What i think should be here is for example textblock.Text = value
        }
    }
```

Comment: The [Property-path syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185586.aspx) article for UWP apps doesn't mention the `Path=.` syntax we know from WPF. No idea however why `<controls:CustomControl Test="{Binding}"/>` wouldn't work, as you haven't shown the declaration if the `Test` property.

Comment: Well, I tried many implementations of the Test property. The current one is:

       `private string test;`

        `public string Test {
         get { return null; }
         set { Debug.WriteLine(value); }
        }`

Comment: Don't post that as comment, it's not getting properly formatted there. Edit your question instead. That said, `Test` must be a dependency property to be the target of a binding.

Comment: A quick look at your bit bucket code and I think you need to create a dependency property: http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

Comment: @CodingGorilla Better refer to [Dependency properties overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185583.aspx). This is UWP, not WPF.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses. I'll try with dependency properties and will post the results.

Comment: @Clemens Sorry, just did a quick search and used the first thing I saw. :)

Comment: Thanks one more time. I managed to solve the issue with the help of dependency properties, a concept I never before tackled.

Also it's worth mentioning that the TextBlock.Text is a DependencyProperty,  something, that isn't noted in the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.text.aspx

A new version of the isolated project is pushed to BitBucket to reflect the changes.

Comment: Basically all xaml element properties are dependency properties - that's why the binding system works :) - You should post your solution as an answer btw.

Comment: Yeah. Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, basically all I had to do was use `DependencyProperty` instead of a normal property. Here is the working solution:

First the control inside the `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding MediaElementId}" >
   <GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <local:CustomControl TextBlockContent="{Binding}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemTemplate>
 </GridView>
```

Then in the custom control `xaml.cs` file:

First is the wrapper exposing the `DependencyProperty`:

```cs
public string TextBlockContentProperty
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextBlockContentPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextBlockContentPropertyProperty, value); }
}
```

Then the `DependencyProperty` itself.

```
     public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBlockContentPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
           "TextBlockContentProperty", 
           typeof(string), 
           typeof(CustomControl), 
           new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)) );
```

Note, that the last argument contains the connection to the `OnTextChanged` function, wherewe have access to the object instance. All of the above are `static`, and we can't use them to change the instance of the object.

Here is how I implemented the instance specific logic. `TextBlockContent` is the normal property, that exposes the `Text` property of a `TextBlock`, that is the content of the custom control.

```cs
    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomControl cc = d as CustomControl;
        string content = (string)e.NewValue;
        cc.TextBlockContent = content;
    }
```

Thanks to everyone, who answered my original question.

Comment: Instead of adding a dependency property _wrapper_ around an existing concrete property, you _ONLY_ use the dependency property, so _replace_ the original property as there is no additional value in have two properties on the class that expose the same functionality.